# Get XML value according to child in variable

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have loaded an external XML and stored it in a variable. Now I have another string variable (dynamic) which contains path to a specific node. I need to find the value of the node according to the path in variable.

External XML Loaded: rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss
(No proxy problem, its being loaded in var. I have checked by tracing the var)

```
private function feedLoad(e:Event):void {
    feedXml = new XML(e.target.data);
    feedRef = "channel.title"; // (This is actually dynamic value, and can go n-level deep)
    title_txt.text = feedXml[feedRef];
}
```

How to reference the child path according to the variable? I have tried:

```
feedXml[feedRef]
feedXml.feedRef
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your string by dots with `var feedArr:Array = feedRef.split(".")`, then iterate through your resultant array down with `xml[feedArr[i]]` which is not an `XML` but `XMLList` (or null), then get each child in order and get next property, and so on. An example, that assumes there is only one requested output ever:

```
var xml:XML = new XML("<foo a=\"X\"><moo b=\"Y\">Moo</moo><bar c=\"Z\"><baz>Meow</baz></bar></foo>");
var foo:XMLList;
var x:XML;
var s:String = "foo.bar.baz";
var a:Array = s.split(".");
var d:XML = xml;
for (var i:int = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (d) {
        foo = d[a[i]];
        for each (x in foo) d = x;
        // here it's best to recurse into X instead of using only last X
    }
}
if (d) trace("d",d.toXMLString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
feedXML.child(feedRef);
```

If you want all the nodes called "title", then you can do a recursive function:

```
function searchXML(xml:*):void {
    var xmlList:XMLList = xml.children();
    if (xmlList.length>0) {
        for each (var xmlItem in xmlList) {
            searchXML(xmlItem);
        }
    if (xml.name() == "title") {
        trace(xml.text());
    }
}
```

Sorry if any errors, I have no way to test this right now.

More about traversing an XML in Actionscript 3 here: [Traversing XML structures](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html)

Comment: feedXML.child(feedRef); works only for first level of child. But here the "feedRef" var can have n level of child. Like: "channel.item.title"

Comment: The title can be an attribute of several nodes. If it's channel.item.title then it's the article's title, if it's just channel.title it's the channel's title. What titles are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: feedRef can be "channel.title" or "child.item.title" both

Comment: actually, value of feedRef is coming from another function which can return path of any node. If its "channel.title", using feedXML.child(feedRef) is not working.